# writing mod_rewrite to load a particular file

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to load a page (/user/profile.php) whenever the URL is sitename.com/u/[user_nicename] 
How to achieve this by mod rewrite ?

I have tried the following but it is not redirecting properly,(shows 404 err)

here is my htaccess content,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/([^/.]+)/?$ /user/profile.php [L]
```

(I have created this .htaccess file in 'u' directory so that when a request like example.com/u/[something] is made, it will look for [something] file, when that is not found it tries to find 'u' directory where I have written this redirect)

Kindly help, all I am trying is to load a particular file ie., `/user/profile.php` whenever a request is like `sitename.com/u/[user_nicename]`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     RewriteRule ^/u/(.*) /user/profile.php [L]
```

Comment: that din't work. still redirect not happening, says page not found.

Comment: you should put it on root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have this `.htaccess` inside the sub-directory `u` is implicit and not required in the rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user/profile.php [L]
```